# wpf User Macros & Environment Variables

Tags: c#, wpf, environment-variables

I'd like to create an environmental variable, or macro to be shared between my WPF application and installer projects.

I know how to do this for a C++ project, since I can create a new property page, create a new user macro and share this with other projects within the solution.

Can I do the same thing in C#/WPF projects?

Answer (score 1):

Use **System.Environment** class.

Method for that is: **System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ()**

and **System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()**

Also note the optional third parameter:

**System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable (variable, value, EnvironmentVariableTarget)** Possible values are: Machine, Process and User

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'd like to create a new environmental variable or macro within the solution and share between projects. The get and set methods above provide access to them, not to create new variables.

Comment: whichever your main project is within a solution, declare the environment variables there in app.xaml.vb(if in WPF) and then set the dependencies to that "main project".